# Open Broadcaster MOV to MP4 conversion

Tags: video, premiere, conversion, adobe-media-encoder, obs

I just used OBS to record an MOV file (4k screen recording). Now I'm having trouble opening it in Premiere. When I import it into Premiere, I get only the audio (no video). File opens fine in VLC, but when I use VLC to convert to MP4, one of two things happen:

- I get an error
- I get an empty file

Furthermore, I tried Adobe Media Encoder, and I get an entirely black-frame file - I can see the black frames in preview, even.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on? I have no idea what codec OBS uses - it doesn't show up in Properties for the file.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Can you open the file with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) and post everything it reports when you go to View -> Text?

Comment: Possibly the same issue as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42175068/5726027).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using OBS Studio? If yes, you should try OBS built-in convertor to mp4. Use File->Convert Recording.

Answer (score 0):

This happens reasonably frequently with Premiere.

The most common fix is to go to your media cache (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Common\Media Cache Files on Windows) and delete all of the files. This will require Premiere to re-generate the preview files when you open your project the next time, but it usually fixes any audio/video related problems.

Comment: This does NOT fix this problem, its a codec issue.